# How can i assign array of object to array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json response `controlOwners` from backend now i want to set response to `$scope.selectedOwners = []` , but its giving me undefined in console any idea what is going wrong here ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.selectedOwners = [];
if ($state.is('app.editControl')) {
          $scope.selectedOwners = angular.copy($scope.controlowners);
          console.log('EDIT CONTROL OWNERS DATA', $scope.selectedOwners);
        }
```

json.js

```
"controlOwners": [{
    "workerKey": -1093,
    "sourceFeed": null,
    "statusLookUpCode": null,
    "externalId": null,
    "createdUserText": null,
    "createdTimestamp": null,
    "modifiedUserText": null,
    "modifiedTimestamp": null,
    "stdId": "ZK84T1N",
    "ccId": null,
    "empClasId": null,
    "deptId": null,
    "fullName": "Rajasekaran, Shanmuga",
}],
```

Comment: what is console.log($scope.controlowners)

Comment: Is it due to the lower casing of $scope.controlowners perhaps? It's defined in the JSON as controlOwners (capital O).

Comment: @webdeb `$scope.controlOwners` is json response

Comment: then there is a typo in your code $scope.control*O*wner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is as I stated in my comment above, that you have the incorrect casing in your reference to controlOwners. You have spelled it with a lower case 'o' ('controlowners'), when it should be upper case ('controlOwners'). And hence you are getting an undefined error.

Comment: You're welcome. Can be tricky to spot those kind of errors :)

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that this isn't a typo. You have both:

```
controlOwners
       ^
```

and

```
controlowners
       ^
```

in the JSON and code.

---

Then if the typo is just in your question and not in your code, and depending on how you're using `$scope.selectedOwners` elsewhere, you might not want to *replace* the reference of the list in the if statement, but rather have it update the existing list (even if you have to clear it first).

But obviously, if your code has *exactly*:

```
$scope.selectedOwners = [];
if ($state.is('app.editControl')) {
```

and not the if in a callback that might be triggered at another time, then ignore that.